# Fluent nHibernate Query => QueryOver, Join, Distinct

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

I try to change that query to `QueryOver<>` to be able to do the `Distinct` operation yet inside the (generated sql) query

```
var result = (from x in Session.Query<Events>()
              join o in Session.Query<Receivers>() on x.ID equals o.ID
              where x.Owner.ID == 1 //the user is the owner of that Event (not null)
                    ||
                    x.EVType.ID == 123 //(not null)
                    ||
                    x.Receivers.Count(y => y.User.ID == 1) > 0 //the user is one of the Event Receivers
              select x.StartDate)
              .Distinct();
```

I tried something like that

```
Events x = null;
List<Receivers> t = null;

var result = Session.QueryOver<Events>(() => x)
                    .JoinAlias(() => x.Receivers, () => t)
                    .Where(() => x.Owner.ID == 1
                                ||
                                x.EVType.ID == 123
                                ||
                                t.Count(y => y.User.ID == 1) > 0)
                   .TransformUsing(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)
                   .Select(a => a.StartDate)
                   .List();
```

but then I got the `Value can not be null. Parameter name: source` exception. Any ideas how can I fix that query ?

### edit

thanks to the xanatos' answer, the final SQL query is correct (I used his 2nd approach):

```
SELECT distinct this_.StartDate as y0_ 
FROM Events this_ 
WHERE 
(
    this_.UserID = ? 
    or
    this_.EventTypeID = ? 
    or
    exists (SELECT this_0_.ID as y0_ 
            FROM Receivers this_0_ 
            WHERE this_0_.UserID = ?)
)
```

Comment: Instead of `x.Receivers.Count` try `t.Count`.

Comment: It sounds like EVType or Owner might be null.  So when you try to reference the ID of either of those, the exception is then thrown.

Comment: @Tony Can you see in logging if the query is executed (so it's an exception thrown after the execution of the query) or not?

Comment: One thing for sure that linq Query doesn't support Distinct(), you can use GroupBy + Select Key instead.

Comment: @BrandonO'Dell I'm sure the `t.Count(y => y.User.ID == 1) > 0` is the reason
@xanatos - the exception is being thrown before the query execution

Comment: @Tony then try to remove it :-)

Comment: @xanatos I can't, because I have to check if the `user ID` exists in that `List`

Comment: @Tony You remove it, do a test and see if it breaks. That line of code can be replaced with some other code.

Comment: @xanatos if I remove that line the query will work, the problem is I need to check that `t.Count(y => y.User.ID == 1) > 0` condition (or somehow replace it to get that query working)

Comment: What happens if you set List<Receivers> t = null to an empty list.

Comment: @Tony are you sure it works against database and not empty list? Have you checked generated SQL? Also - I wouldn't use Linq anymore - it can't even join, it can't batch multiple queries etc. at once so you gonna stick with mixed syntax QueryOver and Linq for super-simple queries

Comment: after reading the answers I see it'll work on an empty list, not the DB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written by @fex, you can't simply do a `new List<Receivers>`. The problem is that you can't mix QueryOver with "LINQ" (the `t.Count(...)` part). The QueryOver "parser" tries to execute "locally" the `t.Count(...)` instead of executing it in SQL.

As written by someone else, `TransformUsing(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)` is client-side. If you want to do a DISTINCT server-side you have to use `Projections.Distinct` .

You have to make an explicit subquery. Here there are two variants of the query. the first one is more similar to the LINQ query, the second one doesn't use the `Count` but uses the Exist (in LINQ you could have done the same by changing the `Count(...) > 0` with a `Any(...)`

Note that when you use a `.Select()` you normally have to explicitly tell the NHibernate the type of the `.List<something>()`

```
Events x = null;
Receivers t = null;

// Similar to LINQ, with COUNT

var subquery2 = QueryOver.Of<Receivers>(() => t)
    .Where(() => t.SOMETHING == x.SOMETHING) // The JOIN clause between Receivers and Events
    .ToRowCountQuery();

var result2 = Session.QueryOver<Events>(() => x)
    .Where(Restrictions.Disjunction()
        .Add(() => x.Owner.ID == 1)
        .Add(() => x.EVType.ID == 123)
        .Add(Subqueries.WhereValue(0).Lt(subquery2))
    )
    .Select(Projections.Distinct(Projections.Property(() => x.StartDate)))
    .List<DateTime>();

// With EXIST

var subquery = QueryOver.Of<Receivers>(() => t)
    .Where(() => t.SOMETHING == x.SOMETHING) // The JOIN clause between Receivers and Events
    .Select(t1 => t1.ID);

var result = Session.QueryOver<Events>(() => x)
    .Where(Restrictions.Disjunction()
        .Add(() => x.Owner.ID == 1)
        .Add(() => x.EVType.ID == 123)
        .Add(Subqueries.WhereExists(subquery))
    )
    .Select(Projections.Distinct(Projections.Property(() => x.StartDate)))
    .List<DateTime>();
```

Note that you'll have to set "manually" the JOIN condition in the subquery.

Comment: so, even if you separate the query to get the ID list (the subquery variable) and the final query (the result variable), only one SQL query is being executed ?

Comment: @Tony Yes, because it's a subquery :-) The QueryOver syntax "maps" nearly 1:1 to the SQL syntax. You could rewrite the whole query by removing the `subquery` variable (inside the `WhereExists`) but it would get quite unreadable. In that way it would be nearly equal to a SQL query.

Comment: cool :-) I didn't know I can just do the `QueryOver<>`, I thought I have to always call `Session.QueryOver<>`

Comment: @Tony There is a difference between the two syntaxes. They are used for different things.

Comment: I'd like to read more about the differences between that syntaxes. Do you have any useful links ?

Comment: @Tony But remember that the best friend of a NHibernate programmer is probably the SQL Profiler to see what queries are generated.

Comment: I think I have everything I need, thanks for your help !

Answer (score 3):

"In QueryOver, aliases are assigned using an empty variable. The variable can be declared anywhere **(but should be empty/default at runtime). The compiler can then check the syntax against the variable is used correctly, but at runtime the variable is not evaluated (it's just used as a placeholder for the alias).**" http://nhibernate.info/blog/2009/12/17/queryover-in-nh-3-0.html

Setting `List<Receivers> t` to empty collection as you did (as you have mentioned in comments) means that you check is event id in local empty collection - doesn't have sense at all.

You can try do your query with subquery (should work but i'm not sure, I wrote it without testing, "by hand"):

```
Receivers receiversSubQueryAlias = null;
var subquery = session.QueryOver<Events>()
                      .JoinQueryOver<Receivers>(x => x.Receivers, () => receiversSubqueryAlias, JoinType.Inner)
                      .Where(()=> receiversSubQueryAlias.UserId == 1)
                      .Select(x => x.Id)
                      .TransformUsing(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity);

Events eventsAlias = null;
var mainQueryResults = session.QueryOver<Events>(() => eventsAilas)
                       .Where(Restrictions.Disjunction()
                             .Add(() => eventAlias.OwnerId == 1)
                             .Add(() => eventAlias.EVType.Id == 123)
                             .Add(Subqueries.WhereProperty<Events>(() => eventAlias.Id).In(subquery))
                        ).Select(x => x.StartDate)
                        .TransformUsing(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)
                        .List();
```

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully this answer can help others.  This error was being caused by declaring

```
List<Receivers> t = null;
```

followed by the query expression

```
 t.Count(y => y.User.ID == 1) > 0
```

The QueryOver documentation states "The variable can be declared anywhere (but should be empty/default at runtime)." Since in this case, the place holder is a List, you must initialize it as an empty list.

```
List<Receivers> t = new List<Receivers>();
```

Otherwise, when you try to reference the Count method, or any other method on the placeholder object, the source (t) will be null.

This however still leaves a problem as @fex and @xanatos, in which it makes no sense to reference Count() from the alias List t, as it won't convert into SQL.  Instead you should be creating a subquery.  See their answers for more comprehensive answer.

Comment: "In QueryOver, aliases are assigned using an empty variable. The variable can be declared anywhere (but should be empty/default at runtime). The compiler can then check the syntax against the variable is used correctly, but at runtime the variable is not evaluated (it's just used as a placeholder for the alias)." http://nhibernate.info/blog/2009/12/17/queryover-in-nh-3-0.html

Comment: @fex - I elaborated a bit more with my answer.  Not sure why it deserved the down vote though as the problem was indeed caused by setting t = null.

Comment: @Brandol O'Dell but it's not caused by setting t = null - NHibernate will never evaluate this value (so null reference is not a problem). The purpose of this null value (known as alias in nhibernate terminology) is to provide compile time check and to avoid creating manual criterias with hardcoded strings. The problem with that was other - query couldn't be created from such expression and setting List<T> to empty list result in that database won't be hit with Count() sql query. If you have been offended by downvote - i upvoted ;)

Comment: @fex - Thanks for the clarification. I see what you are saying, and in this case, modifying the query to use a subquery makes more sense.

Comment: yep - cause now the problem is hidden (it doesn't crash but this line: t.Count(y => y.User.ID == 1) > 0) is always false (it doesn't use db). And that's why we always should log our queries or use tools that do it for us - http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/nhprof